# How to create a GUI to send commands and args to a command-line application?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, cmd, interface

Me and my family use a command line application frequently. It gets tedious because sometimes the amount of chars entered can be a lot. My son asked me if it is possible to make it like a normal program. (He's 10, doesn't even know what a VCR or a touch-tone phone is lol.) Anyhow, I told him that someone would have to write a program for it. He say's he wants to. (I'm thinking I know who's going to take care of me and my wife in the future... lol j/k...) This will be a learning experience for both of us.

So, let's begin his career!

I'm not looking for someone to write the whole thing for us. We just need a good start.

How can we create a GUI for a command-line exe? (The exe is open source and is written in python but for now we'll stick with passing cmd's to the exe and reading its output.)

So we are looking for:

> a textbox for our input, a few radio buttons for args, submit button and a clear button. I guess there should be a place to define the path to the exe.

```
Syntax: command --argument-abc --argument-xyz <textbox-data>

If no options are selected it should default to: command <textbox-data>
The 3 options we basically are starting with are: This way, That way or both
```

> It should show the console output live as its running.

Here is a SS of where we want to start.
[Preliminary Layout](https://photos.app.goo.gl/1o6AvZFnNw5vr6757)

Down the road we will package it together but I think this should be a good start to get us going. The exe has hundreds of different args that will be added over time on an options tab or what not.

We are using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017

Sorry for the rambling.

Oh and one last thing. Please point us to some good articles, how-to's, or anything that you think will help us learn what we need for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a place where programmers bring code that does not yet work. I applaud your son's intentions to get going. Because there are many ways to do this, SO seeks to limit wide-ranging topics in order to avoid conflict and to provide specific answers to specific questions. This would be better asked on https://superuser.com/. You might get a good start on https://poshgui.com/.

Comment: My answer included using Python. If your son starting a career in programming, Python is an important language for him to consider.  Thankfully it's one of the easiest languages to get started in. What tool did you use to get your Python program into EXE form.  You could get the Python source to your exe and have your GUI call it directly rather than launch as a separate exe file.  What is the open source program you are launching?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind doing it in Python, then perrhaps [PySimpleGUI](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will work for you.

There is a Demo program that does exactly this, add a GUI to the front-end of a command-line program.

[OpenSource.com](https://opensource.com/article/18/8/pysimplegui) recently published an article that steps you through how to do this.

Just for fun I've duplicated the GUI you posed using PySimpleGUI. It is under 20 lines of code.

I recently combined my GUI python programs with PyInstaller.  It produces a single .EXE file that runs and shows only my GUI window.  The command I use instructs PyInstaller to hide the dos window.

> pyinstaller -wF my_gui_program.py

[PySimpleGUI Code and screen capture of window](https://gist.github.com/MikeTheWatchGuy/2ba11b1ef55e559e365b8ae862be1eff)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative option is to use PowerShell to do this - the later versions have the `.net` framework built in, and can create user forms like in `vb.net`. If you have experience in `vb.net`, it should make it easier. As an extra advantage, PowerShell can usually use the same (or similar) commands as Command Prompt, so it should be familiar.

Take a look [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/building-gui-applications-in-powershell/240049898) for more information, however a quick google search for PowerShell GUI should be sufficient.

However, MikeyB is quite correct when he says that Python is a good language to learn - it's used in a lot of different areas in the industry (I still personally prefer `vb.net` though, I only looked at Python for a month).